# How to get Optimum Lag with Data2 tends to catch up more on the upside than on the downside of data1

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, statistics

Hope you are doing well!!
I have two time series, Data1 and Data2 from 01/01/2017 to 01/01/2020,
I did a cross correlation with all the dates (from 01/01/2017 to 01/01/2020) to get the optimum lag, however Data2 tends to catch up more on the upside than on the downside, so the lag has to be different, And from 01/01/2017 to 01/01/2020 I'm sure that the lag found with the cross correlation function will not be representative for all data,
My question is How can resolve that ? I mean how can I built a trend indicator to then get the best lag ?
Thanks

Comment: What is your data?  I get that x is time, but what are the y or other axes?  Why do you care about lags?  Is there something cyclic and stationary you are trying to model?  What business question are you trying to answer? What approach have you tried so far.  What architecture are you working within?  Is this R, or Piet?  Do you have toy data?

Comment: Hi, I’m working with R, one of the time serie is the daily price of the futur contrat (stock1) and the second one is the daily price of the same underlying (Stock1), the CCF allows me to optimize the correlation between those series, but the lag will not be the same when the spread between those series increase or decrease

Comment: So the question is how can I find a “trend indicator”, to know which lag I should put in the first time serie